# PIC interrupt on change never enters the interrupt routine

Tags: pic, interrupts

Hello I am using PIC18F26K83 and I have a button on RC7 pin. That is why I cannot use a normal interrupt. But according to datasheet interrupt on change can be used in this pin. I could not make it work so I tried to make a code with interrupt on change which was supposed to make the LED light. But the code never enters the interrupt routine. Here is the code:

```
   #define switch PORTC.B7
#define led1 LATB.B0
#define led2 LATB.B1
#define led3 LATB.RB5
int counter;

 void Clk_8Mhz(){
   //8 MHz clock
          //  OSCCON1 REGISTER
   NOSC2_BIT=1;
  NOSC1_BIT=1;
   NOSC0_BIT=0;//HF INTERNAL OSC
   //OSCFRQ REGISTER HFINTOSC FREQ. SELECTION


OSCCON1 =0b01100000; //HFINTOSC, Divider =1;
    FRQ3_BIT=0;
   FRQ2_BIT=0;
   FRQ1_BIT=1;
   FRQ0_BIT=1;    // 0011 :8MHz     //0100 = 16 Mhz
  }
void main (){
TRISC.RC7=1; //Button pin is output
ANSELC.RC7=0; //Button pin is digital

TRISB=0x00; //B port is output.
LATB.B=0x00; //All B port is initially zero.
//RC7 IOC

//Interrupt initialisation
INTCON0.B5=0; //Interrupt priority disabled
IOCCN7_bit=1; //RC7 pin is negative edge
IOCCF=0x00; //Clear the Interrupt on Change Flag
PIE0.B7=1; //Interrupt on change enabled
INTCON0.B7=1; //Global high priority interrupt enable


   Clk_8Mhz();


while(1){
delay_ms(10);//Wait for interrupt

}

}
void interrupt(void)  {

led1=1;
led2=1;
led3=1;
}
```

Probably I am missing something very obvious.
Edit: I use Micro C
Edit2: I changed to code like above. Still interrupt does not occur unfortunately.

These are 2 images of the schematic, I could not find the whole part but schematic of PIC and switch is in here:

[image: Schematic of the button]
[image: Schematic of the PIC]

Comment: You know switch is a reserved word? (Used in ```#define switch PORTC.B7```)

Comment: I did not know that, but again I did not use it in anywhere. I just defined it.

Comment: which compiler? In xc8 the interrupt specifier uses two underscores.Have a look at the manual. And btw. never use a delay function in an ISR.

Comment: Possible issue: Ensure switch is properly pulled up or down - either by an internal pullup or externally. (No, I didn't check the code, you'll know if you have considered this or not).

Comment: You need to read PORTB before clearing the interrupt flag but since the interrupt is never executed this is not the main reason for the fault

Comment: Yes, it never enters the ISR

Comment: Please try to format your code and remove everything that's not necessary. You're asking hundreds of readers to read through your code, and we don't need to have the code for all your buttons and LEDs. Try to get only one button and one LED to work first, and post that code. Remove everything unused.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set your PPS Registers (page 265/266) also see 9.9 Page 122. This could possibly be the reason for your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I just set RC7 as RC7PPS= 0b00010111, but problem still continues.

Answer (score 1):

PPS should not matter for Interrupt on change, especially if the peripheral is disabled.

You shouldn't need a pull up as that seems to be done in hardware. You can disable the weak pull up
 (below)

`WPUC.WPUC7 = 0`

Another thing you should do is read up on MikroC using their [manual](http://download.mikroe.com/documents/compilers/mikroc/pic/mikroc-pic-manual-v101.pdf) page 121

```
Interrupts can be easily handled by means of reserved word `interrupt`. mikroC
PRO for PIC implictly declares function interrupt which cannot be redeclared. Its
prototype is:
```

`void interrupt(void)`

not

`void _interrupt(void)`

**Set config bit MVECEN to OFF** to make sure Mikro C is not looking for a vectored interrupt.

Also `INTCON0.IPEN = 0; // Disable Interrupt Priority Vectors (16CXXX Compatibility Mode)`

**Update your compiler**. See this [forum post](https://forum.mikroe.com/viewtopic.php?f=88&t=73891) for issues regarding MikroC and K42/K83 pic series.

*You also forgot to set ANSEL for the LED but I don't think this matters for output*

```
ANSELB.B0=0;
ANSELB.B1=0;
ANSELB.B5=0;
```

Comment: Changed both but still no luck

Comment: Hi, If you can also post a schematic on your question it might help in case there might be electrical issues. thanks.

Comment: Sure I am adding it quickly

Comment: You can disable the weak pull up as that is already in hardware. Maybe you should try to organise your code a bit better so it is more easier to read (in case it is a software issue it might be easier to find)

Comment: ps. I noticed you used `WPUC.B7 = 1;` instead of `WPUC.C7 = 1;` in your updated code, I guess that's an error in your stackoverflow code (Again please try to format your code)

Comment: No, WPUC.C7 gave me an error, so I changed it to WPUC.B7 that is WPUx register 7. bit ( Page 257)

Comment: That doesn't seem to make sense if it is PORTC. It should be WPUC.WPUC7 (I don't know what it is in MikroC). Try setting config bit MVECEN to OFF to make sure Mikro C is not looking for a vectored interrupt. and also Disable Interrupt Priority Vectors (16CXXX Compatibility Mode) `INTCON0.IPEN = 0;`

Comment: Yes that is INTCON0.B5=0; that was done

Comment: And the config bit MVECEN ?